# zeromq pub/sub example in c (libzmq)

Tags: c, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Can someone show me "Hello World" example for zeromq pub/sub in c using [libzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq). I have done coding req/rep example It's well documented but I couldn't find good hello world example for pub/sub that works fine with me.
Here is my try.

pub.c

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    char message[15] = "Hello World!";

    while(1)
    {
        zmq_msg_t msg;
        zmq_msg_init_size(&message, strlen(message));
        memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&msg), message, strlen(message));
        zmq_msg_send(publisher, &msg, 0);
        zmq_msg_close(&msg);
    }

    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

sub.c

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    assert(rc == 0);
    zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

    char message[15] = "";

    while(1)
    {
        zmq_msg_t msg;
        zmq_msg_init(&msg);
        zmq_msg_recv(subscriber, &msg, 0);
        int size = zmq_msg_size(&msg);
        memcpy(message, zmq_msg_data(&msg), size);
        zmq_msg_close(&msg);
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }

    zmq_close(subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly, please tell us the problem you have with your code, and we can help you with that instead.

Comment: It almost looks like you missed the ZeroMQ users guide.  Unlike other tooling and APIs in the open source software world, the written guide for ZeroMQ is amazing.  Take sometime, sit back, and just [read the content here.](https://zguide.zeromq.org/) You will find lots of samples in that book (also documented in github...) I was pleasantly surprised on how well that guide was written.

Comment: Pub/Sub is a pretty advanced architecture.. nothing simple about it.  (Espresso Pattern, Last Value Caching, Slow Subscriber Detection, High Speed Subscribers, Clone Pattern... etc...)  Not sure where you are going, but is that the right ZeroMQ architecture for your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this code works with me

pub.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <zmq.h>

int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    int rc = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
    assert(rc == 0);

    while(1)
    {
        rc = zmq_send(publisher, "Hello World!", 12, 0);
        assert(rc == 12);
    }

    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

sub.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <zmq.h>

int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
    assert(rc == 0);
    rc = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    assert(rc == 0);

    char message[12];

    while(1)
    {
        rc = zmq_recv(subscriber, message, 12, 0);
        assert(rc != -1);
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }

    zmq_close(subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```